# Add component to top of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have vertically aligned elements in a `JPanel`, and I want to add one to the first position, not the last one. Is there a way to do that?

I tried using `BorderLayout` and adding all the elements to `BorderLayout.NORTH` but that just replaced it.

Comment: You will need to change layout managers to something that supports allowing multiple components to be displayed within a given container (`BorderLayout` is a little stingy in this regard).  Then you can use `Container#add(Component, int)` to place the component at a given index within the container, if you pass it `0`, it should become the first component to be laid out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GridBagLayout or GridLayout with your JPanel. It will allow you to align your elements vertically. Then you can use `add(Component component, int index)` method provided by `Component` class to add your new component to your first position.